# how to have many Material-ui modal in one page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, modal-dialog

I'm using Next.js and Mateial-ui for my front end project and I want to have many modal on same page and open them separately, I've passing `handleClickOpen()` as props to my modal and it works good but I have some problem with z-index.
when the first one open I can't click on behind buttons to open the other modals.

```
function PaperComponent(props: PaperProps) {
    return (
        <Draggable handle="#draggable-dialog-title" cancel={'[class*="MuiDialogContent-root"]'}>
            <Paper {...props} />
        </Draggable>
    );
}

const [zIndex, setZIndex] = useState<number>(5000);
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
};
const handleZIndex = () => {
    setZIndex(zIndex + 1)
}

<Button style={{
                textTransform: 'lowercase',
                width: '100%',
                minHeight: 100,
                marginBottom: '2px',
                padding: '-5px'
            }} variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                {simplifyStrategy(strategy)}
            </Button>

<Dialog
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                PaperComponent={PaperComponent}
                onClick={handleZIndex}
                disableEnforceFocus // Allows other things to take focus
                hideBackdrop  // Hides the shaded backdrop
                disableBackdropClick  // Prevents backdrop clicks
                aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog-title"
                maxWidth={'md'}
                fullWidth={true}
                style={{
                    top: '85%', // Position however you like
                    left: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)} %`,
                    height: 'fit-content',  // Ensures that the dialog is
                    width: 'fit-content',   // exactly the same size as its contents
                }}
            >
</Dialog>
```

Comment: please upload the code you are using

Comment: I've just upload it

Comment: I should specify, will need all the code you are using to show how the modals are mapped, and what you are using on the `onClose` function, `open`, and `handleZIndex`.

It's much easier to help if we have the entire code, you can comment out sensitive parts

Comment: the whole component is huge but I uploaded functions that you need

Comment: Mapping multiple modals is usually where things go awry.

Is the code you supplied from the modal component, or the component that renders the modal as a child? There's much more needed to identify the problem here.

Comment: Parent render modal as child.
I think my whole strategy is wrong.
whats your idea for this problem?
I want to have something like window in my dashboard.
in current code handleOpen is on the modal component but I think its better to pass it as props from parent component.